# Rewrite url for missing resource

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

For each web request (file or directory) that doesn't start with `/en-US/`, I want to
serve up the original resource if it exists, otherwise serve up the `/en-US/` version.

How would I do this using rewrite rules in a .htaccess file?

Comment: What (if any) rewrite rules are you currently using?

Comment: None yet. All files in /en-US/ are duplicated for each language, which is a nightmare to maintain.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
RewriteCond $0 !^en-US/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule .+ en-US/$0 [L]
```